# Local Binary Patterns Pixel on Border?

Tags: lbph-algorithm

3x3 local binary pattern has 8 neighbors,
**current center** is always `(x, y)`

what if **current center** is on one of the **4 borders**?

eg: `x=0, y=0`, there are only 3 neighbors (right, right-bottom, bottom), what about the rest

how to compose the binary sequence (the "neighbors" out of boundary are considered as `0`?, because its value is not >= center)

```
# my current solution is try coordinate of img
# if it's out of boundary, return 0
# else return neighbor's value
try:
    return img[x, y]
except:
    return 0
```

Comment: Take a look at this thread: [How to calculate the lbp codes at the ends of the images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427999/how-to-calculate-the-lbp-codes-at-the-ends-of-the-images)

Comment: @Tonechas Add 4 extra borders with zero padding, it answered my question. Thanks 